# UITextField in Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield

I've written this code in my CCLayer's "init" method:

```
//textField
    UITextField *tf = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
    tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    CCUIWrapper *tfwrapper = [CCUIWrapper wrapperForUIView:tf];
    tfwrapper.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
    tfwrapper.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 20);
    tfwrapper.position = ccp(100, 100);
    [self addChild:tfwrapper];
```

Why isn't UITextField visible?

Comment: try to use initWithFrame: method of UITextField instead of simple init.

Comment: The same thing... Nothing...

Comment: UITextField *tf = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)] autorelease];

        CCUIWrapper *tfwrapper = [CCUIWrapper wrapperForUIView:tf];

        tfwrapper.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);

        tfwrapper.position = ccp(0, 0);

        [self addChild:tfwrapper];

Answer (score 0):

1. Dunno what's up with CCUIWrapper but you now might want to try CCTextField instead of this approach.
2. Try setting the UITextField's .preferredsize.